# PHP Math with variable not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in mySQL db:  the price field is set as float(25,2).

Why won't this yield a result?

`$refundable = $trial->data()->price - 100.00;`

If I just echo $trial->data()->price I get the record value of 1100.00, but it won't work in this simple math equation.

Nothing shows up as a result for $refundable

Here are my methods:

```
public function find($invoice_id = null) {
        if($invoice_id) {
            $data = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id =" . $invoice_id . "");   

            if($data->row_count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }
```

Comment: How are you outputting the result?

Comment: what is the output of $ `var_dump($trial->data()->price);`the type?

Comment: Also, can you show how the `data()` method works?

Comment: Are you executing the find method before the data method?  If not, the data method is returning null.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

Php may be interpreting the value from your db as a string.  Casting it as a float should work, e.g.

```
$refundable = (float)$trial->date()->price - 100.00
```

Comment: If `price` is a numeric string, subtracting a float from it will create a [numeric context](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) where it will already be evaluated as a number. The explicit cast should not be necessary.

Comment: The var dump is string(7).

Comment: I also updated my question with the methods, as requested

Comment: @Panic, yep, you're right - the cast is indeed redundant.  I just tested it and checked the php reference.  The issue must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, thanks. The math operation WAS working ok. The issue I discovered is that where I was using it, I had to convert it back into a string in order for it to work properly with a certain plugin.

I appreciate the help here.

Without the comments, I would have been lost for a while!